# Express with Browser-Sync

Tags: node.js, express, reverse-proxy, browser-sync

I want to integrate  BrowserSync with express.

I want to pull a URL from the DB and use it as the proxy. However the setup I've come up with initializes a new BrowserSync server for each request.

Is there a way to accomplish this without initializing a new BrowserSync server every time?

Or should I be using another approach?

```
var bs      = require("browser-sync");
var express = require("express");

var router  = express.Router();
var app     = express();

router.get("/", function(req, res){
    bs.create("bs1").init({
        notify: false,
        open: false,
        ui: false,
        port: 10000,
        proxy: 'http://example.com'
    });
        res.send();
});

app.use(router);

app.listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

Comment: You want to pull a different proxy each call?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yes. Ideally I would want a unique subdomain to refer to each proxy url. For example: sub1.mysite.com will always proxy www.example.com. sub2.mysite.com will always proxy www.example2.com. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out this cant actually be done with any ease.

I ended up using express-http-proxy instead and express-vhost for subdomains.

```
app = require('express')();
vhost = require('vhost');
proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use(vhost('sub1.mysite.com', proxy('http://www.example.com')));

app.listen(8080);
```

Hopefully this helps someone one day.